# I want to keyboard input 3 integers and print the maximum value is "X" using if-else statement

Tags: java

In the last if statement, why I cannot use only else statement instead of else if statement, if I entered only else statement, the compiler generates an error saying not a statement.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
class today {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input number 1:");
        int num1 = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Input number 2:");
        int num2 = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Input number 3:");
        int num3 = input.nextInt();

        if (num1 > num2 && num1 > num3) {
            System.out.println("Maximum number is:" + num1);
        } else if (num2 > num1 && num2 > num3) {
            System.out.println("Maximum number is:" + num2);
        } else if (num3 > num1 && num3 > num2) {
            System.out.println("Maximum number is:" + num3);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its giving you error because else statement should not have any condition to validate. Check here to know more about  if else [Read more](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_conditions.asp)

```java
if (hi < 5) {
    System.out.println("ok");
} else {
    System.out.println("no");
}
```

See in above code else statement don't have any condition

so in your case it should be like this.

```java
if (num1 > num2 && num1 > num3) {
    System.out.println("Maximum number is:" + num1);
} else if (num2 > num1 && num2 > num3) {
    System.out.println("Maximum number is:" + num2);
} else {
    System.out.println("Maximum number is:" + num3);
}
```